# Build and Run separate projects in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Short and simple, our project has a Launcher component and an Application component and we would like to 'Clean and Build' the Application but Run should run the Launcher component.

Is that possible? I've been looking into editing the `build.xml` but there might be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you speak about the shortcuts on the top toolbar. They apply to the main project, the one in bold in the Projects pane.

You can **Clean and Build** or **Run** individually every project you have in the Project pane. Open the Project Pane, choose a project, right click on it and in the menu you will find the needed actions.

You can also change the main project : right click on the project -> Set as Main Project.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in Netbeans 7.2: when no main project is set the project specific actions (build, clean - build, etc.) are run on the 'active project'.

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_72_NewAndNoteworthy#Main_Project

This is especially handy when working with multiple projects, you do not have to switch the 'main project' all the time...